# Convert a TRIM on regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a large string and one of the lines is in the form of

```
Description:          something here....
```

I want to get everything in the: `something here...` without any trailing or leading space on it. Currently I'm doing it with a mix of regex and a `strip()`. How could this be done entirely in regex? Currently:

```
re.search('Description:\s+(.+)', body).group(1).strip()
```

Other thoughts:

```
re.search('Description:\s+\w(.+)\w', body).group(1) # works
```

Also, why doesn't putting an anchor work in the above context?

```
re.search('Description:\s+\w(.+)$', body).group(1) # fails
```

Comment: `Description:\s+(.*\S)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect, thank you. Why the `.*` instead of `.+` though? And finally, why does doing `$` fail here? Is there a way to denote 'end-of-line' but not end of string?

Comment: End of line is a place before a line break. You want to omit all the trailing whitespace, so you  want to stop before any trailing spaces, tabs, etc. You need to stop at the last non-whitespace char, `\S` and to get to its last occurrence you need `.*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, but in that case wouldn't `.+` work as well? My understanding was `.*` vs `.+` was that the first allows zero but the second doesn't (everything else the same) -- or is there another nuance that I'm missing?

Comment: The `.` matches any chars but vertical whitespace, it still matches horizontal whitespace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got it, want to post an answer then and I'll go ahead and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of

```
Description:\s+(.*\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JcGoTL/1).

The point is that you need to match up to the last non-whitespace character. `.*` matches any zero or more characters other than line break chars, as many as possible, so the `\S` matches the last non-whitespace character in the string.

If you have a multiline string and you need to get to the last non-whitespace character, you may add `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` option when passing the pattern above to a regex method, or re-write it as

```
Description:\s+(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*)
```

where `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace chars and `(?:\s+\S+)*` matches zero or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces followed with one or more non-whitespace chars.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JcGoTL/2).